# Joomla 2.5 tooltip not separating title::text

Tags: joomla2.5, tooltip

I'm developing a little module, when I hover an image, I want to show a tooltip.

The tooltip part is working ok, but it seems that there is a bug in title::text separation, because everything is placed into tip-title div as follows.

```
<div class="tip">
  <div class="tip-title">Title::Text</div>
  <div class="tip-text"></div>
</div>
```

My tooltip spam looks like this

```
<span title="Title::Text" class="tooltip-class">
  <img src="<?php echo $row->thumbnail; ?>" title="<?php echo $row->title?>" />
</span>
```

Did anyone faced the same issue?

Just for the record, the tooltip is working, so it's appearing when hovering the image, but all tooltip content is placed in the tooltip title div, so no "::" separation done.

Thanks in advise!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I misconfigured  JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip'); I needed to set it up as follows

```
$toolTipArray = array(
    'className'     => 'tooltipsClass',
    'offsets'       => array('x'=>-23, 'y'=>-14),
    'fixed'         => true,
    'windowPadding' => array('x'=>-500, 'y'=>-500)
);

JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip', '.tooltip_data_class' . $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ), $toolTipArray);
```

Best regards!